# How to modified the Gauss–Laguerre quadrature in the case of $\int\limits_{10}^{\infty}{{e^{-x}}f(x)}\mathrm{d}x$?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, laguerre-polynomials

I am not sure if we change the lower limits, How to use the Gauss–Laguerre quadrature. I am considering about substitution the lower limits. It looks like $$\int_{0}^{\infty}{{e^{-(x-10)}}f\left(x-10\right)}\,\mathrm{d}x=\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_{i}f\left(x_i-10\right)?$$

I am not sure it is right. And how the $w_{i}$ and $x_i$ will be changed ?

Comment: It should be $\int_{0}^{\infty}{{e^{-(x+5000)}}f(x+5000)}\mathrm{d}x$ rather than $\int_{0}^{\infty}{{e^{-(x-5000)}}f(x-5000)}\mathrm{d}x$.

Comment: $e^{-5000}$ is practically zero. Therefore, numerically all your integrands are practically zero. In which application arise functions $f$ that give a non zero value to such an integral?

Comment: Thanks. This is indeed make sense. How about change the 5000 to the 10.

Comment: Hint 1: address @Mostafa Ayaz' comment. Hint 2: 
$$
\int_c^\infty e^{-x}f(x)\,dx=\int_0^\infty e^{-(x\color{red}+c)}f(x\color{red}+c)\,dx=\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\,e^{-c}f(x\color{red}+c)\,dx\,.
$$
To which function do you now have to apply the quadrature rule? As a candidate $x\mapsto e^{-c}f(x\color{re}+c)=:g(x)$ comes to mind.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot.